# How to set alias to hyperlink field in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My gridview code :

```
<columns>
                <asp:boundfield runat="server" DataField="title" HeaderText="Title"></asp:boundfield>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="link"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"  DataTextField="link" HeaderText="Download File" />

            </columns>
```

My Code-behind :

```
dt.Columns.Add("title");
        dt.Columns.Add("link");
        while (item.Read())
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["title"] = item["title"];
            dr["link"] = "/download.cshtml?id="+ item["link"];

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        grdData.DataSource = dt;
        grdData.DataBind();
```

My Grid view shows up Like :

[image]

i want it to show "Download" instead of full link, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build HTML inside the datarow. For example:

```
dr["link"] = "<a href='"+ "/download.cshtml?id=" + item["link"] + "'>Download</a>";
```

Comment: lol i was tryin to do that all day and it didnt work, but your code worked magiclly, thanks alot.

Comment: perfect!. Dont forget to mark as answer if it worked. :)